# git rebase to a different branch

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following situation:

```
Master ---X---X---X
               \
   Alpha branch A1---A2---A3---A4---A5---A6
                      \              \
                       \  beta branch B1---B2
                        \
              My Branch M1---M2---M3
```

I want to move my branch to "B2", ending up like this:

```
Master ---X---X---X
               \
   Alpha branch A1---A2---A3---A4---A5---A6
                                     \
                          beta branch B1---B2
                                            \                             
                                  My Branch M1---M2---M3
```

To do that, should I make, in my branch, a `git rebase beta` or should I add the option *--onto* like this: `git rebase --onto beta alpha My`? I had read the documentation, but I still didn't figure out the difference...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's four ways to do it:

- > git rebase <branch>

  Reset checked out branch to <branch>, apply differences (between
  previous HEAD and the common ancestor) and commit.

  ```
  git checkout my
  git rebase beta
  ```
- > git rebase <branch1> <branch2>

  Reset <branch2> to <branch1>, apply differences (between previous <branch2> and the common ancestor) and commit.

  ```
  git rebase beta my
  ```
- > git rebase --onto <branch1> <branch2>

  Reset checked out branch to <branch1>, apply differences (between previous HEAD and <branch2>) and commit.

  ```
  git checkout my
  git rebase --onto beta A2
  ```
- > git rebase --onto <branch1> <branch2> <branch3>

  Reset <branch2> to <branch1>, apply differences (between previous HEAD and <branch2>) and commit.

  ```
  git rebase --onto beta A2 my
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on top of your branch, just saying `git rebase beta` or `git rebase B2` will do. The difference is that by using --onto you can control more tricky situations..... like the opposite: want to move beta branch on top of my branch. If you are on top of beta and run `git rebase my-branch` you would end up with M1--M2--M3--A3'--A4'--A5'--B1'--B2' (because from the point where the branches diverged (A2) revisions A3 to A5 (both inclusive) would also have to be included in a simple rebase. In that case you would have to run: `git rebase --onto my-branch alpha-branch beta-branch`. Hope that clears it up